# Telerik RadGrid export biff format is giving HTML content in columns

Tags: telerik-grid, radgrid, radgridview

I am using telerik ASP.NET AJAX UI control is one of my webform . I am using the format GridExcelExportFormat.Biff. I am getting problem that when I am exporting the file the generated excel file has html content in columns. How can I get rid of that content or best will be to make available the content as on page in file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BiffExporting event of grid, I resolved the issue by using below code:

e.ExportStructure.Tables(0).Cells(View.Columns.IndexOf(View.GetColumn("Revenue")) - _FirstColumnIndex, 1).Value =
            e.ExportStructure.Tables(0).Cells(View.Columns.IndexOf(View.GetColumn("Revenue")) - _FirstColumnIndex, 1).Value.ToString().Replace("
", String.Empty)